# Roll Back Sql Server 2008 query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, rollback

I am inserting values into two tables using two stored procedure , and the data in both tables are linked to each other so i want if any error occurs in second  stored procedure ,the data entered via 1st stored procedure should get roll backed.

I am using Sql server 2008 as my back end and ASP.net (c#) as front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use need to use `TransactionScope` as below

```
using(var tran = new TransactionScope())
{
   //calling stored procedures here
   tran.Complete();
}
```

when an exception occurs the control will go out from the using and thus `transaction` will `rollback`

Comment: Thnxx @reza , it really helped me

Comment: @AkhilRJ You're welcome, you can upvote the post that help you by clicking on uparrow beside the question and you can mark the answer by clicking on Tickmark beside the question to help other people find the right answer in case  they had same question

Answer (score 0):

if you are using entity framework you can use it.

```
using (var  dataContext = new SchoolMSDbContext())
{
  using (var trans = dataContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
  {
    try
    {
      // your query
      trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      trans.Rollback();
      Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can try this

```
 using (var dataContext = new SchoolMSDbContext())
                {
                    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //your query
                            transaction.Complete();

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            transaction.Dispose();
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

for this you'll have to this references.

```
System.Transactions
```

for more information check this links
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could u plz explain why r we using 'TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled ' this parameter..